# Disabling Windows 10 Sleep mode in Corporate

Tags: windows, sleep, hibernate, group-policy

Few days ago, company IT decided that users no longer deserve Sleep Mode in their laptops. I don't want to enter BitLocker pin every time whenever I need to move between meeting rooms as I close lid of my laptop. Earlier this month it went to Sleep mode. Few day ago it started Hibernating.

I'm gathering material to argue with them whether it is good idea or not. Before I will look like total idiot in person, can somebody enlighten me with good reason/scenarios why this policy would be beneficial for corporate environment?

I could not think of any good security or other reason why to do so.

Comment: They've probably done this mainly for Desktop PCs (so people who don't turn off before going home don't use electricity all night) [Here's a good comparison](https://www.educba.com/hibernate-vs-sleep-mode/) that might help you come up with certain arguments as to why laptops should have different power rules set in group policy.

Comment: @Smock As far as I know, there are no desktop PC used for many years. Never seen one around.

Comment: That is an odd decision then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the accepted answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135284/does-hibernate-feature-pose-any-security-threat). Basically with BitLocker, the drive stays unlocked when in sleep mode.